# Asynchronous Loading of vue.config.js for Pre-Rendering Meta Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm attempting to asynchronously load some data in to my Vue.js application's config, to be consumed by Chris Fritz's PrerenderSPA webpack plugin, however - it doesn't seem to be pre-rendering any of the routes.

When I hard code the values - they're prerendered fine, it just seems to fail when attempting to async load the webpackConfiguration.

This is my watered down attempt:

```
const configPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  // API Fetch for Prismic Routes:
  const blogRoutes = await prismicRoutes;

  let renderRoutes = [
    ...generalRoutes,
    ...blogRoutes,
  ];

  // then at some point call `resolve()` with the config object:
  resolve({
    pwa: {
      name: 'App',
      themeColor: '#000000',
      msTileColor: '#000000',
      appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
      appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

      // configure the workbox plugin
      workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
      workboxOptions: {
        // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
        swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
        // ...other Workbox options...
      }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      plugins: [
        new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
          staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
          routes: renderRoutes,
        }),
      ],
    },
  });
});

module.exports = configPromise;
```

Can this be achieved with something like:

```
async function exportConfig() {
  module.exports = await configPromise;
}

exportConfig();
```

Has anyone achieved such an asynchronous loading of the vue.config.js at build time?

Comment: why you dont just grab nuxt.js

Comment: @Ifaruki Yeh - I would, but this is a legacy project.

Comment: Maybe I'm following the question but if you need asynchronously loaded data to be available in your webpack configuration, that is supported. Webpack configuration functions can return promises

Answer (score 0):

The [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/dev-guide/plugin-api.html#configurewebpack) option doesn't support Promises yet, meanwhile you can [fetch the data before running the build](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3328#issuecomment-455788257)

**Additional note:** if some routes fetch data from a remote API *while prerendering*, and the API does not support CORS, you need to configure a [proxy](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin#server-options).

Example:

```
// build.prerender.js
const prerenderConfig = {
  // ...
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: process.env.API_URL,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api' : ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = (api) => {
  // @api refers to vue-cli api
  api.registerCommand('build:prerender', async (args) => {
    const { routes } = await fetch(...)
    prerenderConfig.routes = routes
    api.chainWebpack(config => {
      config
        .plugin('prerender')
        .use(PrerenderSPAPlugin, [prerenderConfig])
        .end()
    })

    await api.service.run('build', args)
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I do something like this in `vue.config.js`?  If I put 

```ts
module.exports = (api) => {
  console.log({ api });
  return {
    productionSourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
```
in `vue.config.js` when running `npm run serve` I get

```js
{ api: undefined }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. This is a workaround for prerendering pages for your Vue application. So it's part of your build. You would typically not run `npm run serve` in that context, rather `npm run build`.